# Find a unique_ptr to an inherited class object emplaced_back in a vector

Tags: c++11, inheritance, stl, move-semantics

I am trying to implement an Entity Component System (ECS) for my game. I have a base class "Component" (referred here as A) which is inherited by child class like HealthComponent(referred here as B), DamageComponent (referred here C)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

class A
{
public:
    A() : VarA(10){}

    int VarA;
    const std::string ClassName = "A";
    virtual void prnt(){ std::cout << "A class" << std::endl; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() : VarB(20){}
    int VarB;
    const std::string ClassName = "B";
    void prnt(){ std::cout << "B class" << std::endl; }

    bool operator== (const B& other) const
    {
        return this->ClassName == other.ClassName;
    }

};

class C : public A
{
public:
    C() : VarC(30){}
    int VarC;
    const std::string ClassName = "C";
    void prnt(){ std::cout << "C class" << std::endl; }

    bool operator== (const B& other) const
    {
        return this->ClassName == other.ClassName;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> ObjVector;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>::iterator ObjIterator;

    A* object1 = new B();
    std::unique_ptr<A> bptr{object1};
    ObjVector.emplace_back(std::move(bptr));

    A* object2 = new C();
    std::unique_ptr<A> cptr{object2};
    ObjVector.emplace_back(std::move(cptr));

    ObjIterator = std::find(ObjVector.begin(), ObjVector.end(), B);

    return 0;
}
```

on compiling the code

```
-------------- Build: Debug in STL (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -g -std=c++11  -c C:\Users\admin\Desktop\code\C++\STL\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\STL.exe obj\Debug\main.o   
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\code\C++\STL\main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\code\C++\STL\main.cpp:58:66: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
   58 |     ObjIterator = std::find(ObjVector.begin(), ObjVector.end(), B);
      |                                                                  ^
```

I tried using "new B()" and "(&B)" as the last parameter in std::find function but it still gave me errors. Please Help.

**UPDATED CODE**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

class A
{
public:
    A() : VarA(10){}

    int VarA;
    const std::string ClassName = "A";
    virtual std::string getClassName(){ return ClassName; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() : VarB(20){}

    int VarB;
    const std::string ClassName = "B";
    std::string getClassName() override { return ClassName; }
};

class C : public A
{
public:
    C() : VarC(30){}
    int VarC;
    const std::string ClassName = "C";
    std::string getClassName() override { return ClassName; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> ObjVector;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>::iterator ObjIterator;

    A* object1 = new B();
    std::unique_ptr<A> bptr{object1};
    ObjVector.emplace_back(std::move(bptr));

    A* object2 = new C();
    std::unique_ptr<A> cptr{object2};
    ObjVector.emplace_back(std::move(cptr));

    ObjIterator = std::find_if(ObjVector.begin(), ObjVector.end(),
                               [](const std::unique_ptr<A>& p)
                               {
                                   return dynamic_cast<B*>(p.get()) != nullptr;
                                });

    std::cout << (*ObjIterator)->VarB << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Your solution worked and i changed some of the code accordingly. It gives me access to methods common to all class, here "getClassName()". But on accessing class specific methods and variables (here VarB, which is specific to class B) it gives me the following error

```
-------------- Build: Debug in STL (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -g -std=c++11  -c C:\Users\admin\Desktop\code\C++\STL\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\STL.exe obj\Debug\main.o   
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\code\C++\STL\main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\code\C++\STL\main.cpp:55:34: error: 'class A' has no member named 'VarB'; did you mean 'VarA'?
   55 |     std::cout << (*ObjIterator)->VarB << std::endl;
      |                                  ^~~~
      |                                  VarA
```

Basically I cannot access the methods and variables that are not included in the base class. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are trying to pass a class name as an argument to a function call. That doesn't make sense, and that's what the compiler is telling you. `&B` doesn't make sense for a similar reason - you can take an address of an object, but not of a type. I don't believe you still get the same error when you replace `B` with `new B()` - you likely still get **some** error, but not the same error. Now, what is it that you want to search for?

Comment: Note that `ObjVector[i]->ClassName` is always `"A"`, never `"B"` or `"C"`. This expression always accesses `A::ClassName`. You seem to expect polymorphic behavior from data members - there ain't no such thing as a virtual data member in C++.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik, I want be able to do something like player.getComponent<HealthComponent>()->health. The whole component creation functionality will be handled by manager. For the sake of simplicity I have named Health and Damage component to B and C respectively. The ObjVector here is called arr_component inside my entity class. What I am trying to do here is to make this "getComponent<HealthComponent>()" functionality. Where I find if I have a certain component in my vector. I have highly simplified the code for better understanding. I could host my original code somewhere if you wish.

Comment: One way would be something like `std::find_if(ObjVector.begin(), ObjVector.end(), [](const std::unique_ptr<A>& p) { return dynamic_cast<B*>(p.get()) != nullptr; } );`

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik, I tried your solution. Now I doesn't give me an error on that line but when I tried to cout *ObjIterator->ClassName, it gave me an error {class std::unique_ptr<A> has no member named ClassName}

Comment: `(*ObjIterator)->ClassName`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I made some changes to my code according to your suggestion, but now it is giving me different error which I have no clue. Please help.

Comment: You have a vector of `A*` pointers. `*ObjIterator` is `std::unique_ptr<A>`, and `A` doesn't have a member named `VarB`. If you want to access members from class `B`, you need a `B*` pointer, as in `B* pB = static_cast<B*>(ObjIterator->get()); std::cout << pB->varB`. Note that at this point, you aren't really using polymorphism - instead of `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>`, you might as well have separate members of type `B` and `C`, and make your life much easier.